# Setting Listbox Item Name Using Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Minimized">
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="copyQuote" Text="Copy Quote" Click="copyText"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="deleteAllFavs" Text="Delete All" Click="delete_All_Favs"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="rateAndReview" Text="Rate and Review" Click="rateApp"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="suggestions" Text="suggestions" Click="emailSuggestion"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="message" IconUri="/icons/appbar.feature.email.rest.png" Text="message" Click="message_favourite"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="share" IconUri="/icons/appbar.message.send.png" Text="share" Click="share_favorite"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="deleteFav" IconUri="/icons/appbar.delete.rest.png" Text="delete" Click="delete_favorite"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,0,0,0" x:Name="favShaListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Yu Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Yu Gothic" Width="480" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Name" Value="{Binding QuoteKey}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

when i try loading this xaml page it throws a exception called XAML parseException pointing at Attribute "Value" in the Setter that was used for styling the Listbox above.

$exception  {"Set property '' threw an exception. [Line: 50 Position: 49]"} System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}

and it points to a application bar item name "copyQuote" where as i clearly stated that the style target only ListboxItem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a Problem in setting the Property of ListboxItem.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Name" Value="{Binding QuoteKey}"/>
                </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

try after removing this `Setter`.

Comment: But i need the Setter to set the Name of the ListBoxItem.